# Sharepoint-2013 Fill field with active users department

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, peoplepicker

I have some code which will look up the user in the SP PeoplePicker and return the department of the user.

What I want to achieve is automatically filling a field with the current user's department, as I do not want the peoplepicker field. Either the current user data should be retrievable or I should be able to search though a peoplepicker without having a peoplepicker field.

So, I add the following script into a content editor:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"></script>

<script> 
    $(document).ready(function()
    { 
        var PeoplePicker = $("div[title='test_column']"); 
        var PeoplePickerTopId = PeoplePicker.attr('id'); 
        var ppobject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[PeoplePickerTopId]; 

        ppobject.OnValueChangedClientScript = function(elementId, userInfo){getUserData()};       
    });

    function getUserData()
    { 
        //Set variables
        var UserDept;
        var i;
        var _PeoplePicker = $("div[title='test_column']"); 
        var _PeoplePickerTopId = _PeoplePicker.attr('id'); 
        var ppobject = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[_PeoplePickerTopId]; 

        // Call GetAllUserInfo to read PeoplePicker entries
        editorsInfo = ppobject.GetAllUserInfo(); 

        // Set Customer Info
        if(editorNames!= null)
            {UserDept = editorsInfo[0].EntityData.Department;} 

        $("input[title='Department']").val(UserDept)
    }
</script>
```

Note, I do not have access to Sharepoint Designer. I am trying to get this working from the web view only.

Additionally, if the answer requires AJAX or returning the value from a httpget post, can you please be thorough with the answer as I have never used AJAX before and have limited experience with receiving responses from web servers.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SPServices Jquery. Just download the latest one. 
You are using Sharepoint 2013 so use Script Editor instead of Content Editor. 
Below is the script i use regularly and works fine.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/your path to JS/SiteAssets/JS/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>  
<script type="text/jscript" src="/your path to JS/SiteAssets/JS/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript">  

$(document).ready(function() {   

 var UserDept = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({  
 fieldName: "Department",   
 debug: false  
 });   
  

 $("input[title*='Department']").val(UserDept); // For assigning to SharePoint column named 'Department'  

 $("#txtDept").val(UserDept); // For assigning to textbox  


});  

</script>
```